# Does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+(-1)^{n}\sqrt{n}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

As you've seen from the title, I'm wondering whether the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+(-1)^{n}\sqrt{n}}$ converges or diverges? I'm struggling!

My first thought was to rewrite it like this to determine an alternating series:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+(-1)^{n}\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(-1)^{n}+\sqrt{n}}$$

After seeing that $\frac{1}{(-1)^{n}+\sqrt{n}}$ isn't a decreasing sequence I can't use Leibniz's theorem (alternating series test). I would be thankful for some guidance on where to go next, I'm stuck!

Comment: Use alternating series test.

Comment: @Andrei Yeah but that fails since it isn't decreasing through infinity.

Comment: But you can squeeze it between $(-1+\sqrt n)^{-1}$ and $(1+\sqrt n)^{-1}$

Comment: @JonathanAxelsson my mistake. Just because the absolute value of each term can be squeezed between the two sequences, it does not mean that they will nicely cancel each other.

Comment: Thanks! @hyper-neutrino

Answer (score 0):

As

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{1+(-1)^{n}\sqrt{n}}&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\frac{1}{1+(-1)^n/\sqrt n}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}+\frac{1}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\\
&= \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}-\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{3/2}}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

the initial series diverges as the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: Did you mean to write "as the harmonic series diverges"?

Comment: The alternating series $\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges.

Comment: I indeed meant as the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: @jjagmath : Which means it cannot rescue the diverging series arising from the second term...